# appendTo div from div and back

Tags: jquery

I am trying to just simply move a div to a another div and back.  It moves from left div to right div, but will not move from right div to left div.  Just appends to the same (right) div.  I've tried it with and without 'div' in the selector, and every other option I could find.  Sorry if this has been answered.

```
<div id="main" class="main">
<div id="left" class="box">

<div id="user1" class=".usersAll">User1</div>

<div id="user2" class=".usersAll">User2</div>

</div>
<div id="right" class="box">
</div>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('div#left div.usersAll').on('click', function () { 
        // move from "left" to "right"
        $(this).appendTo("#right");
    });

     $('div#right div.usersAll').on('click', function () { 
       //  move from "right" to "left"
        $(this).appendTo("#left");
    }); 
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

As the element isn't there when the event handler is bound, you probably want to delegate

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#left').on('click', '.usersAll', function () { 
         $(this).appendTo("#right");
    });

     $('#right').on('click', '.usersAll', function () { 
         $(this).appendTo("#left");
    }); 
});
```

And you don't want the period in the className in the HTML

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#left').on('click', '.usersAll', function () { 
        $(this).appendTo("#right");
    });
    
    $('#right').on('click', '.usersAll', function () { 
        $(this).appendTo("#left");
    }); 
});
```

```css
#left {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

#right {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  left: 200px;
  top: 0;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main" class="main">
  <div id="left" class="box">
    <div id="user1" class="usersAll">User1</div>
    <div id="user2" class="usersAll">User2</div>
  </div>
  <div id="right" class="box">
  </div>
</div>
```